# I can't click the quality button in Youtube android

Tags: android, youtube

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzMAd.jpg)

My version is 10.52.53.
The middle is quality button, i can't click to change quality, always watch 144p

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show your code how you are doing?

Comment: i just watch livestream normally